# Правильно делать приватные методы Java статическими или нет? Плюсы и минусы каждого варианта?

Tags: java, ооп, классы, архитектура, best-practice

В английской версии видел этот вопрос, но в русской версии не нашел. Часто некоторые программисты используют `private static` методы, чтобы показать что этот приватный метод не использует никаких переменных и методов класса, другие наоборот против этого подхода так считают его не правильным использованием ООП (речь только о **приватных методах класса**, не использующих никаких переменных класса и других не статических методов).

То есть, что правильнее по вашему использовать так

```
   public class MyClass {      
      private static void func1() { // со статик
        ...
      }
   }
```

или так

```
   public class MyClass {      
      private void func1() { // без статик
        ...
      }
   }
```

?

Я говорил о тех методах, которые не используют (и не могут использовать) поля напрямую, например метод `boolean isValid(T str)`, который вызывается в других методах класса для множества различных объектов, и которые нужны исключительно только для этого класса и выносить их в отдельный `Utils` класс нет смысла.

Как пример такого метода это `hugeCapacity` в `ArrayList` из `Oracle JDK 8`:

```
private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

**P.S.** Любые цитаты и ссылки на известных Java авторов очень помогут решить вопрос (скажем, я знаю, что в `ArrayList` из `Oracle JDK`, где авторы довольно известные Josh Bloch  и Neal Gafter, используется `private static` методы). Может вы знаете другие подтверждения той или иной точки зрения?

То есть идеальный ответ, это ответ с цитатами на книги / статьи известных Java авторов или тех кто занимался теорией ООП или проектирования.

Comment: с точки зрения правильности оба варианта корректны, с точки зрения производительности - private static является лучшей подсказкой компилятору для оптимизации и инлайнинга

Comment: `речь только о приватных методах класса` - все же именно "только о приватных методах класса" или "о приватных методах класса, которые не используют никаких переменных и методов класса" ?

Comment: Которые ничего не используют и которым без проблем можно поставить static. Вопрос именно в том нужно ли.

Comment: Обычно, если в коде попадается первый вариант, это говорит о том, что метод не на своем месте.

Comment: Хм, ну бред же ради оптимизации делать метод статическим. Если статические методы быстрее, то это вопросы к компилятору, он должен смотреть зависит ли метод от членов класса и делать соответствующие оптимизации самостоятельно

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Руководствуйтесь смыслом, и только им. Строение ваших классов должно отображать не техническую *возможность* сделать так или иначе (иногда экземплярные методы *можно* объявить статическими), а отношения между объектами в доменной области. Это и правда база всего ООП (а где ж ещё следовать ООП, если не в Джаве?).

Я не могу привести цитату из умной книги по этому поводу. Но сама идея делать сигнатуру метода зависимой не от его *смысла*, а от подробностей его конкретной имплементации кажется мне грубым хаком. Даже если это внутренний, приватный метод. Если в публичных методах, предназначенных другим, мы пишем правильно, то почему в методах, предназначенных для себя, писать неправильно?

Для отступления от правильного дизайна нужны веские причины. У `ArrayList` такие причины есть: он используется в миллионах проектов, и среди них есть критические по времени куски, и там выигрыш пары тактов играет серьёзную роль. Но для большинства классов, которые мы пишем, количество вызовов в наших программах не исчисляются десятками тысяч в секунду, и отступление от правильного дизайна вряд ли оправдано.

---

Если метод относится к конкретному объекту, то объявляйте его экземплярным методов вне зависимости от того, обращается он к нестатическим полям и `this` или нет. Если метод общий для всего класса, и не имеет смысла в контексте отдельного экземпляра, объявляйте его статическим. Если метод вовсе не относится к классу, вынесите его во вспомогательный класс.

---

Пример: оружие рыцаря — меч. Да, у всех рыцарей одинаковое оружие. Тем не менее, метод, выдающий оружие — это очевидно экземплярный метод. Далее, рыцари не пользуются кинжалами. Поэтому геттер кинжала у рыцаря возвращает `null`. Это тоже экземплярный метод.

```
class Knight : Warrior {
    private Weapon createMainWeapon() {
        return new Sword();
    }
    private Dagger getDagger() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Далее, количество рыцарей. Соответственно оно не имеет смысла в контексте одного рыцаря, значит, является статическим методом.

```
class Knight : Warrior {
    static int numberOfKnights;
    public Knight() {
        numberOfKnights++;
    }
    public static int getNumber() {
        return numberOfKnights;
    }
}
```

Ну и наконец, метод, который выясняет, в порядке ли амуниция перед битвой, вообще не относится к сфере деятельности рыцаря. Пусть этим займётся оруженосец!

```
class Squire {
    Knight master;
    public prepareForBattle() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы за количество рыцарей отвечал класс KnightArmy, а не статический метод рыцаря?

Comment: @AseN: Угу, или так. Но я бы избегал чрезмерного создания сущностей, чтобы не получилось [так](https://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

Answer (score 12):

Во-первых, для начала хорошо бы определиться, а нужен ли этому классу данный метод? Скажем, есть у нас класс машины и метод по переводу километров в мили.

```
public class Car {

    private static double convertToMiles(double km){
        return km*0.621371192;
    }   
}
```

Очевидно, что этот метод вообще не нужен классу и его хорошо бы вынести в отдельный `final` `Utils` подобный класс, так как может быть использован много где.

Renaud Waldura в "The Final Word on Final" пишет:

> Since a final method is only implemented in the declaring class, there
>   is no need to dynamically dispatch a call to a final method, and
>   static invocation can be used instead. The compiler can emit a direct
>   call to the method, bypassing entirely the usual virtual method
>   invocation procedure. Because of this, final methods are also
>   candidates for inlining by a Just-In-Time compiler or a similar
>   optimization tool. (Remember, private/static methods are already
>   final, therefore always considered for this optimization.)

Я лично делаю по возможности `static`, чтобы показать, что метод не зависит от состояния класса и никак на него не влияет. В IDE такой метод будет выделен italic шрифтом, что позволяет понять о его независимости от состояния класса, даже не заглядывая внутрь метода.

Comment: Тут вопрос немного в другом. Вы описали случай когда метод не нужен, а автору интересно, если этот метод нужен то каким вы его сделаете static или обычным?

Comment: @Виктор `static`. Точно так же, как если переменная присваивается один раз, я сделаю её `final` и т.п. Это всё из одной оперы.

Comment: Отдельной проблемой являются Util-классы, представляющие из себя по сути "взлом" оо-идеи и скрытный возврат к функциональной парадигме. Что обычно плохо, особенно в больших проектах.

Comment: @AseN `Math` класс?

Comment: Math-класс - отличный пример описанной одним комментарием выше проблемы, где все свалено в кучу.

Answer (score 6):

Сразу обозначу ИМХО: метод не должен быть статическим и в посте стараюсь описать эту точку зрения.

---

Каждый сам творит свой код. Может быть это актуально для оптимизации, но не для ООП. Получается это не метод, а процедура.

Цитата из интервью David West:

> "Класс ничего не должен делать"
>
> Егор: Но в Java классы — не просто формочки для объектов. Мы туда помещаем методы…
>
> Дэвид: А зря!
>
> Егор: Вот в этом и мой вопрос!
>
> Дэвид: Ну, как я попытался сказать в книге, класс ничего не должен
>   делать. В Smalltalk есть методы классов, но не надо их использовать.
>   Их использование — возвращение к командному способу мышления. Вы
>   берёте то, что должно быть ответственностью объектов, и по каким-то
>   причинам пытаетесь запихнуть это всё в класс. И в итоге класс делает
>   многое за объекты.

[интервью полностью](https://jug.ru/2016/09/bugayenko-west/)

---

Все сводиться к одному вопросу, почему этот метод должен принадлежать классу, а не объекту?

---

Сейчас подумал, что эта цитата не в тему вопроса, но пусть останется.

Я не совсем понимаю с какой целью делать приватный метод статическим. Если только для оптимизации.

Если не брать в счет оптимизацию, то метод оперирует полями объекта (просто переданы они будут как параметры). И тут можно вспомнить "чистый код". Чем меньше у метода параметров, тем проще он читается. Значит можно сделать его не статическим и использовать не параметры, а поля объекта.

Если приватный метод не получает никаких параметров и не обращается к переменным объекта, то не совсем понимаю, что он будет делать.

---

> Update: Я говорил о тех методах, которые не используют (и не могут
>   использовать) поля напрямую, например метод boolean isValid(T str),
>   который вызывается в других методах класса для множества различных
>   объектов, и которые нужны исключительно только для этого класса и
>   выносить их в отдельный Utils класс нет смысла.

Валидность объекта может определить сам объект и тут нужен "информационный эксперт" и тогда суть дженерик метода уходит в каждый класс, т.е. вместо статического метода валидности любого объекта мы спросим сам объект валиден ли он.

Comment: Честно говоря совсем понял как ваш ответ отвечает на изначальный вопрос. Вы какой точки зрения придерживаетесь в итоге, правильно понимаю что статические приватные методы не нужны?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin дополнил, если честно то не совсем представляю проблему, точнее когда это можно использовать. Цитату привел как общую, т.к. вчера наткнулся на статью и показалось подходит, но не совсем

Comment: Метод может не оперировать полями, а в любом случае принимать параметры, например метод boolean isValid(T str), который вызывается в других методах класса для множества различных объектов. Ну и скажем, он исключительно только для этого класса.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin если этот метод используется в пределах этого же класса, то вся разница будет в указании параметра метода. И тут подходит цитата "Класс не должен ничего делать", объект сам может сказать валидный он или нет.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, пример такого метода hugeCapacity в ArrayList из Oracle JDK 8.

Answer (score 6):

Для более глубокого понимания добавлю исторический контекст вообще о статических методах. Некоторые исследователи  вопроса вообще считают все подобные методы злом в ООП.

Когда тема трудна для понимания, то один из лучших способов - обратиться к истории. Java произошла от Smalltalk. Это знают все кто хоть один день потратил на его изучение. В языке Smalltalk (с 1971 года) уже были статические методы - правда они там идут под названием "методы класса". Откуда же они появились там? Smalltalk имеет еще одного предка - Simula (с 1965 года). Оказывается и в Simula были такие методы - только там они идут под названием "свободный блок". Но в свою очередь кто "протащил" с язык Симула эти "свободные блоки"? А предок Симулы - Алгол. Потому что Симула изначально  надмножество Алгола 60. 
Так что вот откуда ноги растут:

а) Алгол

```
procedure Absmax(a) Size:(n, m) Result:(y) Subscripts:(i, k);
    value n, m; array a; integer n, m, i, k; real y;
comment The absolute greatest element of the matrix a, of size n by m
    is transferred to y, and the subscripts of this element to i and k;
begin
    integer p, q;
    y := 0; i := k := 1;
    for p := 1 step 1 until n do
        for q := 1 step 1 until m do
            if abs(a[p, q]) > y then
                begin y := abs(a[p, q]);
                    i := p; k := q
                end
end Absmax
```

б) Simula

```
Begin
   Class Glyph;
      Virtual: Procedure print Is Procedure print;
   Begin
   End;

   Glyph Class Char (c);
      Character c;
   Begin
      Procedure print;
        OutChar(c);
   End;

   Glyph Class Line (elements);
      Ref (Glyph) Array elements;
   Begin
      Procedure print;
      Begin
         Integer i;
         For i:= 1 Step 1 Until UpperBound (elements, 1) Do
            elements (i).print;
         OutImage;
      End;
   End;

   Ref (Glyph) rg;
   Ref (Glyph) Array rgs (1 : 4);

   ! Main program;
   rgs (1):- New Char ('A');
   rgs (2):- New Char ('b');
   rgs (3):- New Char ('b');
   rgs (4):- New Char ('a');
   rg:- New Line (rgs);
   rg.print;
End;
```

Таким образом ООП изначально было надстройкой над императивным - поэтому совсем "выпилить" статические методы не удастся. В институциональной экономике есть такое наблюдение - приоритет/важность правила определяется только одним - стоимостью его изменения (или отмены). "Отменить" статические методы будет стоить человечеству столько человеко-лет, что видимо они с нами навсегда. Мы только можем уменьшить их использование в собственном коде с целью более удобной работы с объектами.

Что касается именно приватных статических методов - к общим недостаткам статических методов добавляем еще и приватность. Очень редко встречал такие методы в коде. Сам не использую, так как стараюсь вообще минимизировать статические методы в коде и отношу себя к сторонникам идей Егора Бугаенко.

Comment: В чем недостаток "приватности"?

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, это самое краткое пояснение смысла использования `static` методов.

> Статические методы следует применять в двух случаях.
>
> • Когда методу не требуется доступ к данным о состоянии объекта, поскольку все необходимые параметры задаются явно (например, в методе Math.pow ()).
>
> • Когда методу требуется доступ лишь к статическим полям класса.

Хорстманн, Кей С. Java. Библиотека профессионала, том 1. Основы. 10-е изд. стр.157

Answer (score 4):

Первым долгом хочу сказать это мое мнение это мой опыт!
(Я думаю что вы знаете суть обычного и статического метода поэтому не пишу определение.)

1. Статистический метод - **это функциональный подход.** В
   объектно-ориентированном проектирование это влияет на разработку
   то есть сопровождение сложно, мышление меняется на функциональность
   и так далее **(общий ответ)**.
2. Ну с точки зрения с **памяти, обычный или статический метода** нет
   потери почему: В **памяти** ".NET/Java" используется техника **Flyweight**
   (даже у этого техники есть паттерн но суть не в этом). **Это техника
   экономит оперативной память** (я не буду подробно объяснять технику), и вот
   здесь обычный или статический метод не влияет никуда (с точки зрения памяти), потому что у каждого класса выделяется один **объект**(это технический имя) который методы содержаться в этом объекте, а каждый **экземпляр** только содержит **обычный** `Fields/Properties` (изменчивый) и эти экземпляры ссылаются на этот **объект**, вот и краткие суть. (здесь подразумевается технический влияние).

Хочу затронуть на один момент. Проблема в том что по-любому обычный или статический метод нельзя нагружать большой ответственность или большой объем кода (один из важных принципов). **Я думаю что не надо так критически смотреть на эту тему.**

Не буду по философски сказку рассказывать. Ну вот разделил на две части **(анализируйте)**.

Ну и могу рекомендовать философскую книгу по этим темам **"Object Thinking David West"** здесь подробно объясняется чистый объектно-ориентированное программирование/мышление архитектурное различие и такие темы как статический , обычные (методы , классы) и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Нет неправильно. Точнее неправильно делать приватные методы класса статическими. Технически конечно это можно делать, но по смыслу есть случаи когда это вредно и не нужно.

Приведу пример: часто вижу, в том же самом Android, когда объявляется новый супер-пупер API, то при изучении исходников, выясняется, что просто сделали ранее приватный метод в классе публичным. То есть Google активно использует приватные нестатические методы в качестве способа управления версиями. Смысл простой, есть приватный метод, который скрыт внутри класса и активно используется нормальными публичными методами, таким образом метод проходит своеобразную обкатку в реальных условиях. Далее после изучения багтреков команда разработчиков решает вывести наружу метод: объявляется сигнатура метода как `public` и опля готово - прогеры получают в руки новый инструмент API.

Считаю, что это очень хорошая практика. И хотя бы ради такого способа объявлять приватный метод статическим не стоило бы.

Comment: Не совсем понял, а в чем разница в этом случае? Можно и private static поменять на public. И другие методы могут использовать оба варианта.