# В каких случаях использовать модификатор static?

Tags: c#

Часто вижу на msdn.microsoft.com методы помеченные как static.
И у меня возник вопрос в каких случаях применять этот модификатор?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members раздел Static Members

Comment: Вот хорошие примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748372/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-java-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4/748394#748394

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В тех случаях, когда код этого метода не использует нестатические члены класса. Поясню на примере:

```
class Foo 
{
    public int SumInstance(int a, int b) 
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    
    public static int SumStatic(int a, int b) 
    {
        return a + b;
    }        
}
```

В этом весьма утрированном примере есть класс с двумя методами, суммирующими два числа. Первый метод экземплярный, а второй - статический.
Чтобы использовать первый метод, вам нуджно сделать что-то наподобие:

```
int res = new Foo().SumInstance(10, 20);
```

Чтобы воспользоваться вторым методом, достаточно нааписать

```
    int res =  Foo.SumStatic(10, 20);
```

Результат один и тот же, но вполне очевидно, что для такой задачи, как сложение двух чисел нет необходимости создавать экземпляр класса Foo, так как никаких экземплярных членов в нём не задействовано. А вот если бы класс выглядел скажем так

```
class Foo 
{
    private int _value;
    
    public int Sum(int a) 
    {
        _value += a;
        return _value;
    }             
}
```

То в этом случае сделать метод `Sum` статическим уже не выйдет: в нём используется нестатическое поле `_value`.
Если класс содержит тоьлко статические члены, то он тоже может быть помечен модификатором `static`.
Можно считать, что статические члены класса принадлежат не экземпляру, а всему типу. Разницу можно увидеть в таком примере:

```
class Foo 
{
    public static int StaticValue  { get; set; }

    public int InstanceValue { get; set; }

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StaticValue = {0}", StaticValue);
        Console.WriteLine("StaticValue = {0}", InstanceValue);
    }
   
}


// где-то в коде
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

Foo.StaticValue = 20;
foo1.InstanceValue = 10;

foo2.Write();
```

Этот код выведет на экран такие строки:

> StaticValue = 20
>
> InstanceValue = 0

Так как статическое свойство `StaticInstance` "принадлежит" всему классу `Foo`, и изменения в нем видны из любого экзземпляра. А вот нестатическое свойство `InstanceValue` "принадлежит" конкретному экземпляру, и поэтому изменение его для `foo` не затрагивает такое же свойство в `foo2`.

Тут ещё стоит отметить, что C# - объектно-ориентированный язык, и в нём не разрешаются глобальные переменные и глобальные функции (как скажем это есть в С++). Однако статические свойства, поля и методы являются аналогом глобальных объектов.

Comment: К примеру у меня тестовые методы не используют ничего не статического и все что нужно создают внутри себя. Значит их надо объявлять статик?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov да, можете объявить. Хотя конечно тут нужно говорить о конкретном коде

Comment: а вообще использование static дает какое-то преимущество?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov 1. немого более чистый код (в том смысле, что разработчик прямо указывает, что этот метод не использует экземплярных членов класса) 2. Нет необходимости создавать экземпляр класса

Answer (score 1):

Методы стоит помечать как *static*, если внутри них не используются не статические члены класса.

Comment: Вы так говорите, как будто я должен помечать все методы, не обращающиеся внутри к нестатическим членам помечать ключевым словом `static`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, это вполне себе рекомендация. Если внутри метода нет обращения к не статическим членам, стоит сделать этот метод статическим, если не ошибаюсь, студия сама порекомендует.

Comment: Не порекомендует (было бы странно). Может R# балуется - не знаю. Но однозначно нельзя так сказать, что если не используются нестатические члены, то метод надо делать статическим. Примеров много. Штатный метод GetType(), например: `public Type GetType() => typeof(MyClass);` Или метод, который возвращает какой-то коэффициент и может быть перегружен в наследниках: `public virtual int GetCoeff() => 10;` и т.д.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, у метода GetCoeff уже есть модификатор virtual. С `GetType` хороший пример, но весьма специфичный. В остальном рекомендация вполне остается рекомендацией. Если бы это было правилом - компилятор бросал бы ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Ну так почитали бы там же.

Модификатор `static` используется для объявления статического члена, принадлежащего собственно типу, а не конкретному объекту.

Модификатор `static` можно использовать с классами, полями, методами, свойствами, операторами, событиями и конструкторами, но нельзя — с индексаторами, методами завершения или типами, отличными от классов

(Взято с MSDN)

Comment: можно использовать, а можно не использовать, вот автор и задал вопрос, а когда использовать?

Comment: ну из описания понятно, что использовать тогда когда хотите чтобы член (в  вопросе метод) принадлежал типу, а не объекту.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто.
Ваш код должен моделировать отношения между объектами.

Если метод относится к конкретному объекту, он должен быть экземплярным. Если метод относится ко всем объектам данного типа, он должен быть статическим. Если метод вовсе не относится к объекту, ему не место в данном классе.

---

Техническая *возможость* объявить метод статическим в отрыве от смысла не является достаточным основанием. Иначе вы бы все методы, тело которых состоит из `throw new NotImplementedException()`, нужно было бы делать статическими.