# Зачем нужен статический экземпляр класса?

Tags: c#

Зачем нужен статический экземпляр класса?

```
class A { }

class Program
{
    static A objA;
}
```

Comment: статический экземпляр класса нужен затем что бы хранить состояние класса в целом, а не отдельного объекта. И поэтому мы можем обращаться к этому полю по имени класса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В каких случаях использовать модификатор static?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796926/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-static)

Comment: Строго говоря это поле не нужно, оно нигде не используется. Да и оба класса не нужны, они ничего не делают. Если хотите узнать что такое static, то лучше наверное почитать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members) или поискать [уроки](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.6.php) на эту тему.